# Design sharing and feedback app

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for a simple web app that will let me share designs with clients and receive feedback. The ability for the client to annotate the design would be nice.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three big tools for this:

- [Notable](http://www.notableapp.com/)
- [redmark](http://www.redmark.com/)
- [ConceptShare](http://www.conceptshare.com/)

ConceptShare has a free 30-day trial. Notable also has a free account for up to 3 users. It's made by ZURB, a fantastic design and usability shop, so I'd probably start there.

Good luck!

Comment: Notable is the sort of think I'm looking for, although I think the pricing is a bit high.
I have found a new Start-up in the UK with a simple to use interface for both the Freelancer and their Clients, its called Notebox http://www.noteboxapp.com

Answer (score 1):

[Google Docs Drawings](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=28131) might work for you.

> With Google Docs drawings you can easily create, share, and edit drawings online. Here are a few specific things you can do:
>
> - Edit drawings online in real time with anyone you choose, and invite others to view your edits in real time.
> - Chat with others who are editing your drawing, from within the drawings editor.
> - Publish drawings online to the world as images, or download them in standard formats.
> - Insert text, shapes, arrows, scribbles, and images from your hard drive or from the Web.
> - Lay out drawings precisely with alignment guides, snap to grid, and auto distribution.
> - Insert drawings into other Google documents, spreadsheets, or presentations using the web clipboard, then tweak them inline.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I have used this before but it's too complex, what I want to do is upload a design (Photoshop, Wireframe, Image etc) give the client a link , they login via the browser and leave comments etc.

Answer (score 0):

Coda Notes is a pretty slick Safari plugin that lets clients mark up designs quickly.

http://www.panic.com/blog/2010/07/coda-notes-for-safari-now-available/